# Move saved file to another directory in PHP

Tags: php, file, directory, move

Here's my code first of all:

```
 /* Make directory if not existing */

$directory = "appicons/$artistid/$appid/";
if (!is_dir ($directory)) 
{
     $mode = 0777;
     mkdir($directory, $mode, true);
}

 /* Resize Icon */
 include('appicons.php');

 if(file_exists(''. $artistid . '-' . $appid . '.png')){
    end(&$appicon);
    }else{

    $appicon = new SimpleImage();
    $appicon->load($icon);
    $appicon->resizeToWidth(128);
    $appicon->save(''. $artistid . '-' . $appid . '.png');

    }
```

$appicon saves a file to the root directory of my website as $appid-$artistid.png. I'd like that file to be moved to the correct directory (which takes the format /appicons/$appid/$artistid/.

I've looked at move_uploaded_file but I'm not sure how to implement it, or if that is the right function I should be using. I believe I should be editing `$appicon->save(''. $artistid . '-' . $appid . '.png');` but I'm unsure what to do...

Comment: Why do you prefix the `save()` parameter with nothing? `$appicon->save(''. $artistid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
$appicon->save($directory . $artistid . '-' . $appid . '.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `$directory` variable isn't concatenated correctly, you want to be using something along the lines of:

```
$directory = 'appicons/' . $artistid . '/' . $appid;
```

If the PNG file can only be saved to the path the PHP script is running for, then you will need to let it save first, and then move the file. If this is the case, then the `rename()` function in PHP will achieve what you're looking for.

```
$filename = $artistid . '-' . $appid . '.png';
if(file_exists($filename)) {
  rename($filename, $directory . '/' . $filename);
}
```

This will move the png file to the directory as specfied (ie the appicons/artistid/appid folder).